# Unable to Connect to SQL Server - A Network-related or instance specific error

Tags: sql-server

I get the following error each time I try to connect to SQL Server, as shown in the image:

[image]

I have followed the instructions from the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci

The error is only thrown when I attempt to login from a remote computer. However, I can login from the local machine.

I have turned off firewall and tried everything imaginable but to no avail.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a domain account to connect to the SQL Server instance? Are you using the same computer for connecting remotely and locally? I guess that you have to enable remote connections to the server from the SQL server settings (in case you haven't yet). Just saying since you say the issue is not presented when connected locally.
Please update with more details about the scenario so we can help better.

Comment: Thanks for getting in touch. I'm not sure how I could be using the same computer to connect remotely and locally. However, the problem only occurs only when I try to connect remotely. Its a SQL Server that is installed for testing purposes - it isn't part of a domain (standalone). I have enabled remote connections.

Comment: I meant to say its SQL Server 12.0. Further suggestions most welcomed - I've at this now for at least 3 days

Comment: I know this is basic stuff but have you tried to verify TCP connectivity to the server?

Comment: Do you mean to try and connect using its IP address rather than its name?

Comment: OMG! You beauty .. connecting via it IP address worked.. I feel like an idiot. Thanks Humberto

Comment: Glad it worked, it's a matter of perspective. Don't forget to mark this question as answered so it can be seen as that.